# Click event isn't working on iPhone 4s

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am using a simple jQuery toggle in my website. I tested it on few devices including Android phones, iPad, iPhone 7 and some desktop PCs. But this problem **happened only in iPhone 4s** (version 9.3.5)

```html
<li>
  <div class="mobile-menu-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div id="nav-icon4" class="toggle-canvas-menu">
        <span>test</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

```js
$('.toggle-canvas-menu').click(function() {
  $('body').attr('id', 'msg-body');
  $('#msg-body').toggleClass('open');
  $('.toggle-canvas-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

I did a quick research and found that css fix (applying cursor:pointer to the element). And also changing to onclick event didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

give this a go -

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle-canvas-menu', function() {
  $('body').attr('id', 'msg-body');
  $('#msg-body').toggleClass('open');
  $('.toggle-canvas-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Otherwise try a checkbox/label method with css to trigger the menu.